# Jackson: "(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize"

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization, lombok

Altought the problem might sound simple, I'm facing this exception on a very simple bean as well:

```java
@Data
public class Foo {
  private List<Error> errors;

  @Data
  public static class Error {
    private int code;
    private String message;
  }
}
```

The JSON:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    "message": "bla bla bla"
  ]
}
```

The exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of "org.example.app.Foo$Error" (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('message')`

The app:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = context.getBean(ObjectMapper.class);
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("request.json");
    try (InputStream stream = resource.getInputStream()) {
        Foo foo = objectMapper.readValue(stream, Foo.class);
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON file resides on the classpath.

What I've tried:

1. Explicit `@AllArgsConstructor` Lombok annotation on `Error` class
2. Switching from `int code` to `Integer code` (nullable type)
3. Moving `Error` class out of `Foo` (non-inner class)

Comment: That's not valid JSON. `message` should be in an object.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, unless you made a typo when copying here..

Comment: OMG! I can't believe that. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using ***@Jacksonized*** annotation with ***@Builder*** as per

https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized

Fix your json object as well as it is malformed. "Errors" is using array of objects, so you should have something like:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "message": "bla bla bla"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Could you update your answer to also include what've been told above?

Comment: mark my answer if it's correct and you are satisfied with it :)